# How to print only Users list and Access level from /etc/sudoers?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, awk

We have multiple servers and i would like to print users list and access level using bash.

I tried below command but could not get exact result what i wanted to:

```
awk '/Allow root/{p=5} p > 0 {print $1; p--}'   /etc/sudoers
```

above command just give me five entries as below

```
## 
root    
abcd
ghfd
fcff
```

but I should get the O/P as below:

```
UserList      AccessLevel
root           ALL
abcd        !/usr/bin/*
```

Can i get the output as above?

Answer (score 0):

After doing so much experiments i am able to achieve it as close as possible by below command.

```
grep "ALL=(ALL)" /etc/sudoers | awk  '{ print $1 "\t""\t""\t" $3 $4}' | cut -d '#' -f1 | cut -d '%' -f1
```

and the output is as below:

```
xxxx                    ALL
xxxxxx                      ALL
xxxx                 ALL


xxxx                        NOPASSWD:ALL
abcd                 ALL
xxxx                 ALL
```

But still i am getting space separated output. i want to skip that spaces in output.